# How does one find out how many bits a file has in one command?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, filesystems, files

I know I can use `ls -lat` to find out how many bytes has a file and then multiply by 8 to find out how many bits. But is this possible in only one command line?

Comment: I don't think so. I also don't see any practical use for a feature like that ^^

Comment: @MartinvonWittich - internet speeds are often done in '**bits** per second'...

Comment: @wilf: Minus protocol overhead.

Comment: In my case I am using this suit test: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documentation_software.html and the parameter is the number of bits I want to analyse.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With GNU `du`:

```
du -b FILE | awk '{ print $1 * 8 }'
```

Comment: Except it doesn't need `bc` - `awk` can do math itself: `du -b FILE | awk '{print $1 * 8}`

Comment: See also `wc -c < FILE` for a portable equivalent (for non-regular files, it has the side-effect of reading them, though)

Answer (score 5):

A shell + GNU coreutils solution:

```
echo $(( 8 * $(stat -c%s FILE) ))
```

The `-c%s` option to `stat` returns just the file size in bytes, eliminating any need for additional text processing.  This syntax is supported by GNU coreutils and therefore should work under most linux distributions.

As an exception on linux, if one is running zsh with the optional zsh/stat module, then one needs to specify a path to get the GNU coreutils:

```
echo $(( 8 * $(command stat -c%s FILE) ))
```

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for the info.  Answer updated.

Comment: It seems a good explanation, thank you. However in my test this command returned to me: title:7: bad math expression: operand expected at `%s '
]2;echo 4096000  ---- the answer is 4096000, but what are the other errors?

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli I cannot reproduce that error and I do not see any circumstance that would both (a) give that error message, and, at the same time, (b) give the right numerical answer.  Curious.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in one line, because you can put several commands on one line, e.g. connected by pipes or command substitutions:

```
echo $(stat -c %s FILE) '* 8' | bc
```

(Thanks @frostschutz for the update).

Comment: Worked like a charm to me. ➜  tmp  stat random-file-3 | sed -n 's/Size: \([0-9]*\).*/\1 * 8/p' | bc
➜ 4096000

Comment: Won't work in non-English locales or on non-GNU systems or for a file called `ZSize: 5` for instance

Comment: how about `stat -c %s FILE` to print size directly, instead of the `sed`?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `find` (predates GNU `stat` by decades):

```
find file -prune -printf '%s*8\n' | bc
```

Relatively portably:

```
ls -ld -- "$file" | awk '{print $5*8;exit}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Single file:

```
wc -c yourfile | awk '{print $1*8}'
```

Mutiple files:

```
wc -c yourfile1 yourfile2 | awk '{$1*=8; print $0}'
```

This one also works for a single file. It is not completely bulletproof though, see *Stephane*'s comment.

*These are POSIX standard compliant commands.*

Comment: Great. Awesome. ➜  tmp  wc -c random-file-1 random-file-2 random-file-3 | awk '{$1*=8; print $0}' 
 ➜ 32832 random-file-1
 ➜ 49152 random-file-2
 ➜ 4096000 random-file-3
 ➜ 4177984 total

Comment: Note that it has side effects if the files are not regular files. The second one would display a `a    b` file as `a b` (sequences of blanks converted to a single space, trailing blanks removed).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas with what kind of non-regular file did you try please?

Comment: Any type (fifos, sockets, doors, devices, directories...). You'll have issues with filenames containing newline characters as well. You may want  to add a `NR == 1`